# Is one permitted to watch tv or movies with immodest women?

Tags: halacha, women, technology, tznius-modesty, men-male

Is a man permitted to watch tv or movies that feature immodestly dressed women?
Assuming one will not have improper thoughts, is it prohibited to look at an immodestly dressed woman on a screen? 
Are images on a screen included in the prohibition of ervah? 
Is there any limmud zechus for the common practice of watching tv or movies?

Comment: Something to think about. Historically, Jewish books have contained many nude images.  http://blog.chron.com/iconia/2012/06/nudity-was-conspicuous-in-renaissance-jewish-books/

Comment: Your question asks even if they don't have bad thoughts,that I personally believe is an impossibility when it comes to the programs of today.

Comment: Yes, it was acceptable in Jewish books. http://seforim.blogspot.com/2013/03/borders-breasts-and-bibliography.html?m=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chacham Ovadia in Yechavei Daas 4:7 writes that seeing a woman on tv is the same as seeing an actual woman when it comes to hirur (thoughts) and there is an issur of lo tassuru achrei levavchem...however when it comes to reading shema that's a discussion which he talks about whether its mutar or not,but an issur of seeing a picture of a woman who is not dressed properly is assur,he brings many sources.

The [Rivevos Ephraim 6:pg 576](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35083) also discusses this issue of seeing a womans hair on tv,but also mentions the issur of tv.

Rabbi Nebontzol in his Kuntres Hanhagos writes tv is assur,and if one is in a room with someone who has inappropriate pictures he can take them down without permission.

Comment: What is the issur of tv that the latter two sources mention? The first source at least explains what he is talking about.

Comment: Same idea ,they write many issurim are involved

Comment: Same idea as what? The first source correctly does not make up an "issur tv".

Comment: They write that many issurim are involved,they are probably referring to the same issur of lo sassuru... And I have seen other commentaries say other issurim,Chacham Ovadia is main source but Rivevos and Rav Nebantzol also add to the same idea even though it is not an actual woman it is assur because of hirhur(not written explicitly,but obvious)

Comment: How does lo sasuru imply an "issur tv"? Why can't you just say what they actually say instead of being vague and adding interpretation without saying so?

Comment: Rav Nebantzhol only writes "many issurim"  he does not elaborate that's what I said initially !